# Asking multiple permissions one at a time

Tags: android, android-permissions

The code just shows dialog box for the first permission and not for the other two permissions.How can I handle multiple requests in a much easier way other than this , in which the app prompts for each permission one at a time .

The code for requesting permission is as follows :

```
package com.example.hp.requesting_permissions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     {
             if  (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
             }

         } else {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Denied",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if   (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new   String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "denied",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,     Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if   (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,      Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new     String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 3);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new     String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 3);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "denied",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]     permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Denied",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                 if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
             break;
            case 3: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,     Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Denied",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: internet and  COARSE_LOCATION permission do not get from user even you are working with marshmallow it's define only manifest file. But you access multiple permissions one at a time then please check below script i ans it.

Comment: Added answer for your reference you can customise it as per your need. You need to put all permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` here only critical/dangerous group permission will go. You can know more about permission group [here]https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Answer (score 0):

**Here it ask all permissions**

```
public class RequestUserPermission {

private Activity activity;


// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
};

public RequestUserPermission(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public  boolean verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permissionWrite = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionRead = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if ((permissionWrite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
            (permissionRead != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS,
                REQUEST_PERMISSION
        );
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public void providePermission(){
    verifyStoragePermissions();
}

public void forceFullOpenPermission(){
    if(!verifyStoragePermissions()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SelectUserActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
                    },
                    10);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Akshansh please check my comment on your post you can easily understand  what i say. in my code when i check permission it also declare  in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code by changing `PERMISSIONS_ARR` to your need or you can customise it to your need.

**Add these code at top of class - global**

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1;


private static String[] PERMISSIONS_ARR = {
    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
};
```

**Call below function where you want to ask permission**

```
public void askForPermission() 
{

// Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_ARR, REQUEST_PERMISSION);


} 
else 
{
    // Permission already given do whatever you want...
}
}
```

**Add below code to track which permission is granted by user and which denied. Take decision according to that.**

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) 
{

if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) 
{
    // for each permission check if the user grantet/denied them
    // you may want to group the rationale in a single dialog,
    // this is just an example
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        String permission = permissions[i];
        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            //Permission denied you can ask it for again.
        }
    }

    if (count == permissions.length)
    {
        // All permission granted
    }
    else
    {
        // Not all permission granted, controlled launch of application.
    }
}
}
```